# Laravel Dusk clear() sends previous value in Nova

Tags: laravel-dusk, laravel-nova

I'm writing some Dusk tests for a Nova resource. When I do

```
$browser->type('@answer', 'Foobar')
$browser->clear('@answer');
$browser->click('@submit-button');
```

the validation should prevent me from submitting the form, but the value `Foobar` is saved instead.

The previous non-blank value `Foobar` can be seen in the request sent via `xhr` to the server. Changing the test to:

```
$browser->type('@answer', 'Foobar');
$browser->type('@answer', ' '); // a single space instead of a blank string
$browser->click('@submit-button');
```

does work, but it's unexpected behaviour for the blank string or `->clear()` to not work.

- Laravel: 5.7.19
- Nova: develop
- Dusk: 4.0.4

How can I actually clear an input field?

Comment: Are you using Dusk 4.0.4+? Then take a look at https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/596.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Based on the last comment I saw on the github issues page, using `$browser->clear('@ answer')->keys('@ answer', 'A', '{backspace}');` works as a workaround. I don't have the same issue with the second lot of text being appended to the first.